# _CastError (type 'String' is not a subtype of type 'Map<String, dynamic>' in type cast)

Tags: flutter, dart

[this is the code where I get an exception](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ep2qg.png)

I tried so many solution but did not work.

Comment: Can u share your json response

Comment: E/flutter (29682): [ERROR:flutter/runtime/dart_vm_initializer.cc(41)] Unhandled Exception: type 'String' is not a subtype of type 'Map<String, dynamic>' in type cast
E/flutter (29682): #0      Products.fetchAndSetProducts
package:shoppingnewapp/providers/products.dart:93
E/flutter (29682): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter (29682):
Restarted application in 2,934ms.
I/flutter (29682): {error: Permission denied}

Comment: yes, this is what i got as respone

Comment: Is line no.75 throwing err ?

Comment: I want to know whether line no.75 throwing err or your model class throwing this err

Comment: there is no error showing , only show the exception while its run

Comment: _TypeError (type 'String' is not a subtype of type 'int' of 'index'), this exception is raised

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Try this**

```
    Future<void> fetchAndsetProduct() async {
        final url = Uri.parse(
            'https://shoppingapp-ef04b-default-rtdb.firebaseio.com/product.json');
        try {
          final response = await http.get(url);
          Map<String, dynamic> extractedData = json.decode(response.body);

          if (extractedData == null || extractedData["error"] == "Permission denied") {
            return;
          }

          final List<Product> loadedProducts = [];
          extractedData.forEach((prodId, prodData) {
          loadedProducts.add(Product(
           id: prodId,
           title: prodData['title'],
           description: prodData['description'],
           price: prodData['price'],
           isFavorite: prodData['isFavorite'],
           imageUrl: prodData['imageUrl'],
        ));
      });
        _items = loadedProducts;
         notifyListeners();
      } catch (error) {
         throw (error);
      }
   }
```